# what are the disadvantages of the JAVA inorder to work with .NET platform?

Tags: java, .net

I am working in java environment past 2 years.But i don't know much about .net.So, I would like to know what are the significant advantages of using .NET instead of using java platform.ie, Advantages of .NET compare than JAVA...

anybody differentiate for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous advantages using .NET instead of Java. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228358%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) should get you started on checking out the differences in the programming language.

As for the platform, you will see that most (if not all) of the framework components you used in Java will be available in .NET

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a strong technical argument you can make either way.  However I would say...

I would assume .NET has better ms-windows/ms-office integration.

Learning .NET has the advantage of making more jobs open to you. esp jobs which require both technologies.